# Getting the correct FCM Registration Token for Firebase Cloud Messaging using Ionic Native Push

Tags: cordova, android-studio, push-notification, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having issues with retrieving the correct FCM registration token in order to send push notifications to specific devices in an Ionic 3 app.

I have tried implementing examples such as the [Ionic Native Push Plugin Example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/), the [Angularfirebase implementation](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic-native-with-firebase-fcm-push-notifications-ios-android/) and the [Push Notifications in Ionic example by Ankush Aggarwal](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59). However, all the examples, when I try to retrieve the token, seem to give me the same registration token. When I try to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send to a specific device (specifying the FCM registration token retrieved from each of these APIs giving me this token), the message fails.

However, I can send to entire devices. I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717038/ionic-app-receive-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging) where the user seemed to have a similar issue as well as the solution of using topics as a workaround.

My testing process goes like this:

1.Remove the current platform and add the new updated platform using

```
ionic cordova platform remove android && ionic cordova platform add     
android
```

2.Open the platform folder in android studio. Add the googleservices.json folder for integration with Firebase.

3.Sync the gradle build and run it on the emulator (for reference, Nexus 5X API 28). Use Inspect Devices on Chrome (which is chrome://inspect/#devices) to see the registrationId.

4.Attempt to send a test message using the Firebase Cloud Messaging that uses the registrationId using Firebase Cloud Messaging. It follows this format: "eJAPP91Mq_Q:APA91b...." and is 174 characters long.

5.The test message fails.

6.Attempt to send the same message, but directed to all devices in Firebase Cloud Messaging. The message succeeds and is displayed on the emulator.

Here is the relevant code in Ionic posted in `app.component.ts`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from "@ionic-native/push";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,
              private fcm: FCM, public push: Push ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      this.registerPush();
  });
}
  registerPush() {
    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        senderID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      },
      ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: true,
        sound: 'false'
      }
    };
    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) =>
    {
      console.log('Received a notification', notification)
    });

    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
      console.log('Device registered', registration)

    });

    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => {
      console.error('Error with Push plugin', error)
    });

  }

}
```

Relevant packages/plugins needed for this (From Ionic Native Push Doc)

Cordova plugin: phonegap-plugin-push

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/push
```

[Repo of the source code](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

[Firebase Cloud Messaging Status for Messages Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpszM.png)

IDE: Webstorm

What I have checked so far:

SenderID: It can receive messages if Firebase sends to all users, so I doubt this is the issue.

Package name issue: See above.

Possible wrong token: Seems to be disproven by multiple methods of getting the token generating the same device token.

Let me know if you need more info! 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It turns out, the phone-gap plugin does not support emulators. However, it did work for messages sent to all devices which is left unexplained. I theorize that it is because it sends a different type of payload that fits in line with what the plugin expects.

I found out my code works for a real device (courtesy of my friend) as well as having the topic method work too, so I am marking this as closed.